# Android - Implement search bar with one click

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, searchbar

I'm trying to implement a search bar on the main Activity of my app. For that, I used the documentation from the [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).

I followed the instructions, and I have my search bar where I can put some query. The problem here is that for the few first time when I try to make a search, I have to click 2 times on a search icon.

First, my bar looks like a default one : 
[Search bar by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1URnQ.png)

I notice that the icon is not clearly white, it's like there is some transparency in it, but I've selected a full white icon.

Then after a click on the icon, my bar looks like this : 
[Search bar clicked one time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYnQ.png)

The icon goes to the left and I have a back button as I was already in the search field.

When I click on the search icon again, I finally have the result that I want : 
[Search bar in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLRkL.png)

When I quit the search bar and do it again, it's the same for 1 or 2 times, and then, I have the normal behavior, I go from the first image to the last just with one click.

Here's my files :

menu_app.xml

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search"/>
```

OnCreateOptionsMenu in MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, s);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, s);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Finally found the solution to my problem, I used a SearchView from the class android.widget.SearchView with a Toolbar from the support librairie so that why the behavior wasn't good, just changed

`app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` 
to 
`app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

and it works well now !

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it, please look at my comment for the solution.